# Having trouble rotating a 3-dimensional list of chars in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, functional-programming

I'm relatively new to Haskell and functional programming but right now I'm working on a project where I attempt to solve 3D-cube puzzles.

I have the following 3-Dimensional list where `' '` represent empty space and `'C'` represents a part of the structure:

```
myShape = [["CC", " C"], [" C", "  "]]
```

I want to be able to rotate this structure along all three axises to try it in different positions. I know that I can rotate it along one axis by independently rotating every 2D-layer.

My question is: How can I rotate along the other axises without hard-coding the rotations?

Comment: Let us forget about Haskell for one moment. How would you rotate the matrix yourself (for example in pseudo-code)?

Comment: Probably by some combination of reverseing and transposing the matrices. But I can't figure out which orders of these give the correct results.

Comment: Hint: first do some experiments with rotating a 2D matrix: for example a 3x3, then aim to generalize it to an nxn.

Comment: [`transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) might come in handy.

Comment: I assume all the lists have the same length? So this is a list of N lists, each of which is a list of N lists each of which is a list of N characters?

Comment: Nope, they don't have to be bounded by a square. For example `[["CCC", " C "]]`. Of course i could  always pad them out if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i solved myself:

```
rotate2dArr :: [[Char]] -> Int -> [[Char]]                                                                                                                                                              
rotate2dArr arr 0 = arr
rotate2dArr arr r = rotate2dArr (transpose $ [reverse row | row <- arr]) (r-1)

rotateX :: [[[Char]]] -> Int -> [[[Char]]]
rotateX arr 0 = arr
rotateX arr r = rotateX (transpose $ [reverse plane| plane <- arr]) (r-1) 

rotateY :: [[[Char]]] -> Int -> [[[Char]]]
rotateY arr 0 = arr
rotateY arr r = rotateY (rotateX (rotateZ (rotateX arr 1) 1) 3) (r - 1)

rotateZ :: [[[Char]]] -> Int -> [[[Char]]]
rotateZ arr r = [rotate2dArr plane r | plane <- arr]

rotate3dArr :: [[[Char]]] -> Char -> Int -> [[[Char]]]
rotate3dArr arr axis r = case axis of 
        'x' -> rotateX arr r -- Rotates cube on x axis backwards 
        'y' -> rotateY arr r -- Rotates cube clockwise as seen from above
        'z' -> rotateZ arr r
```

It might not be all that pretty but it works

Comment: Your list comprehensions are really all just `map`. Rotating an even number of times about an axis can probably be optimized to skip the `transpose`. Bonus challenge: optimize sequences of rotations about arbitrary axes, assuming all the lists in the same direction have the same length (m * n * o).